# Website running slow due to client OS

Tags: windows-10, performance

We received a message saying:

**Blackboard slowness with Windows 10**
*We have received reports of slowness with Blackboard and the latest versions of Windows 10 (Version 1703: Build 15063.13). We are working to resolve this but, in the meantime, recommend users avoid installing the update before ...*

Blackboard is a learning management website that we use.

Is there any reason that the speed of a website would depend so strongly on the client's OS?

Comment: No; They are talking about Edge support.  '15063.13' isn't even the current 1703 build, i believe its '15063.240'

Comment: The slowness is specifically within the browser and it might not be limited to just Edge but very very likely that's what that horrible company meant

Comment: @Ramhound it is .250

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks; I knew it was 200 something;